# Has anyone else noticed a inflection point in their scores?

Tags: discussion

My activity on CV has not changed drastically over the past year or so, but I have noticed that lately, the past few months, I'm getting significantly more upvotes on my historical posts. Looking at the graph on my CV profile, there's an obvious change in rate of point accumulation.

[image]

Is anyone else seeing a similar trend?

Comment: Sometimes a post of yours gets traction without you knowing. For example, people might link to your answer elsewhere, and then it starts having more exposure due to the number of pageviews. Increased visitors might translate into more upvotes, if the visitors have an account here

Comment: But from what @gung said in their answer, it seems like you got upvotes in different posts, so that wouldn't be the case

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may have picked up a fan.

I looked at the reputation over time plots for the 36 highest reputation users (the [first page of users](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), sorted by all time reputation), and I don't see any others with such an inflection point.  I likewise looked at the users with reputation ~10k (i.e., similar to you, in that respect), and I once again see no others with that pronounced change in slope.

Your inflection point comes about halfway into the portion of 2020 that has elapsed so far.  If I look at your plot of reputation changes per day for 2020, I see that you started getting a higher density of upvotes around the beginning of April.

[image]

If I look though the [individual posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11867/cam-davidson-pilon?tab=reputation&sort=post) associated with those upvotes, they are mostly all unique.  That suggests someone has started systematically reading your old posts and upvoting many of them.  Since you have a finite number of posts, this phenomenon won't last forever, but enjoy it while it does.

Comment: Nice use of data to build a hypothesis!

Answer (score 9):

It was nice while it lasted! Goodbye, sweet fan!

[image]